# Multiple sliders in one html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still learning how to code and I have run into an issue. I am making a website where I would like to have multiple image sliders although only the first one works correctly, the images on the other sliders won't show. I imagine I'm missing some code to complete this although I don't know what. The code that I have added is how to create a slider. My question is how do I use this code to create multiple sliders in one html file where all work. For example like copying the slider and paste a new in the same file with different images where all of the sliders should work. Help is much appreciated.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        function plusSlides(n){
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
        function currentSlide(n){
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        function showSlides(n){
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {
                slideIndex = 1;
            }
            if (n < 1) {
                slideIndex = slides.length;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        }
```

```css
.slideshowContainer{
 width:43.2em;
 height:23.15em;
 margin-top:1.5em;
 margin-left:1.5em;
 background-color:#FFF;
 box-shadow: -0.05em 0em 0.5em 0.05em rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: -0.05em 0em 0.5em 0.05em rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -moz-box-shadow: -0.05em 0em 0.5em 0.05em rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mySlides{
 display: none;
}

a.right{
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px;
 float: right;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-top:-268px;
 z-index:1;
 position:relative;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

a.left{
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-top:-268px;
 z-index:1;
 position:relative;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

a.right:hover, a.left:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.dot{
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 12px;
 width: 12px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 background-color: #BBB;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.dotsCenter{
 text-align: center;
}

.active, .dot:hover{
 background-color: #717171;
}

.fade{
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
 from{
  opacity: 0.6;
 }
 to{
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@keyframes fade{
 from{
  opacity: 0.6;
 }
 to{
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshowContainer">
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="exampel1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="exampel2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="exampel3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="exampel4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <img src="exampel5.jpg">
                    </div>
                    
                    <a class="left" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                    <a class="right" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                    
                    <div class="dotsCenter">
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating your code won't work because of lines like these

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

Which will affect all the sliders since all of them have elements with the class `mySlides`.

Changing all the class names and ids in all the code (html, css, js) should work. But it's of course much better to first **understand** your code so that you can reuse it more efficiently.

Comment: Which ids do you mean? So you simply mean that I need to write the same code for example 3 times with all different names? The dots class as well?

Comment: I'm saying it will work, but most of it is redundant.